# Getting Fonts to Match Between Tex Files

Tags: fonts

I am writing a thesis and am forced by my University to use a dated and clunky `MySchooThesis.cls` class file. It is incompatible with many modern packages so I am generating all my figures and graphs in a separate directory using unconnected (e.g. no subfiles) `.tex` files. I would like to make sure the fonts in my figures/plots are consistent with the main document.

When I include the command `{\meaning\rmdefault}` in my thesis file it prints `long macro:-¿cmr` which I assumes means it is using Computer Modern Roman. In my separate `.tex` files where I generate my plots, I am using LuaLaTeX with the `fontspec` package. I tried setting `\setmainfont{CMU Serif Roman}` but when I compile a figure and add the command `{\meaning\rmdefault}` it prints `macro:->CMUSerifRoman(0)` which does not appear to *exactly* match the font returned for the old thesis-based class.

Any ideas on how I could get these to match? Or are they really the same and I'm just getting hung up over names?

Comment: It's not really possible to answer your question since you haven't indicated whether you employ glyphs just from the basic ASCII set of glyphs, or glyphs that fall outside the ASCII set. If it's the former, you shouldn't be able to detect any meaningful differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you spot the differences in the following picture?

[image]

The two sets of verses are typeset with *different* fonts: one with CMU Serif and the other with cmr10.

> ! The top one is cmr10, the bottom one is CMU Serif

Actually there are differences. This is what happens if I superimpose the two sets of verses on each other:

[image]

Yes, there are some tiny differences. The main one revealing here is the kerning between “v” and “a”: the letters are a bit more spaced out in CMU Serif.

I don't think that anybody can decide between the two fonts by just looking at them. Well, if they look in the PDF file they can see that different fonts are used.

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ICRSSR+CMR10                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes      4  0
JOJMQZ+CMUSerif-Roman-Identity-H     CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
```

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate you showing me this. Is it possible to set the font to cmr using `setmainfont`? I tried `setmainfont=cmr` but that gave an error. I understand they are visually very close…but I would like to make them exactly the same if possible and it isn’t too burdensome to do so.